# pgAdmin 1.12.0 and sql-assistant doesn't work together

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Since upgrading to final 9.0 postgresql latest sql-assistant (5.1.10) doesn't work with pgAdmin 1.12.0 Any ideas why so? Or anybody knows any similar to sql-assistant software to work with postgresql 9.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL 9.0 comes with a new version of pgAdmin in order to work with it. It obviously contains changes (d'uh). You probably just need to wait for a new version of sql-assistant that's compatible with 1.12 - your best bet is to contact the vendor of that and ask when they expect to release a compatible version.

You could downgrade to pgAdmin 1.10 via the separate packages available, but that isn't compatible with 9.0, so it's likely to break a lot more than it fixes.